# Not showing negative results in Numbers.app

Tags: macos, spreadsheet, iwork, iwork-numbers

How can I make iWork Numbers not show me negative results?

For example: The thing is that in `A1` I have number 101 and I am doing `-A1` from `B1`. `B1` is empty (because I am waiting for the result) so in `C1` (which is the result of the `A1/B1` calculation) it is showing me `-101`.

I dont want to see any result in `C1` before I receive the missing result from `B1`.

Comment: Can you maybe show a screenshot or something? I'm not sure I'm fully getting this.

Comment: How can I send you the screenshot??

Comment: NOW SHOWING B1(empty) - A1(101)= -101

Comment: empty-101= -101
I WANT: empty-101=empty or empty-101= 0
Finisht: 110-101=9

Comment: You know, the button that says "upload image" when you [edit] your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer disregards the fact that the result is negative, but it will not show you a result if the conditions are not correct.

[image]

For the sake of clarity, if formala in B4 is `=IF(B3="","",B2-B3)

The after shot (when B3 has a value) looks like this:

[image]

This is from Numbers 09.

Comment: Thank you wary much man!!!! I love you!!! I was looking for it a long time!

Comment: FWIW, that is the same formula I would have used in Excel. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Mikel Also, please accept Kirk's answer below by clicking the green checkmark if it helped you.